# Need to set envirionment variable when using Azure Key-Vault Connected Service in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, .net-core, azure-keyvault

When creating a .Net Core application in Visual Studio 2019, I selected the Key Vault option in Connected Services. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/key-vault/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service) documentation page explains what is changed inside the project. Part of that change is adding an envirionment variable:

```
ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUP__KEYVAULT__CONFIGURATIONVAULT
```

After adding the connected service you still have to call config.AddAzureKeyVault using ConfigureAppConfiguration in BuildWebHost yourself. In the same documentation they use a hardcoded endpoint. I cannot find anywhere where the variable is used. So where and how is this variable used?

Answer (score 0):

> So where and how is this variable used?

Actually, when you refer to the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service#access-your-secrets-in-code), the keyVaultEndpoint could easily get vaule from `GetKeyVaultEndpoint`. So you do not need the `launchsettings.json` to set variable.

If you want to use `launchsettings.json`, you could use the following code to get `keyVaultEndpoint`.

In Program.cs:

```
var keyVaultEndpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUP__KEYVAULT__CONFIGURATIONVAULT");
```

In launchsettings.json:

```
{
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUP__KEYVAULT__CONFIGURATIONENABLED": "true",
    "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUP__KEYVAULT__CONFIGURATIONVAULT": "https://yourkeyvaultname.vault.azure.net/"
  }
}
```

You could refer to this article to [use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2#development).

Comment: Any update now? If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)

Comment: Connected Services does change the launchsettings code, it was not changed by hand. Using the hardcoded method GetKeyVaultEndpoint() as the tutorial suggests doesn't seem right. And your answer does not explain where the variable is used.